# Apache Ignite connection between two nodes

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I've recently started to learn about Apache Ignite and I have a newbie question. I'm trying to create 2 ignite node (1 server node and 1 client). I successfully started server node, but when I try to start client node I'm getting an error:

```
[04:23:19,478][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-0-#29%testGrid-client2%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception.
class org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioException: null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1595)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:1516)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1289)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioRecoveryDescriptor.ackReceived(GridNioRecoveryDescriptor.java:195)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2.onMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:559)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2.onMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:330)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:270)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.onMessageReceived(GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.java:123)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:2332)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:918)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1583)
        ... 4 more
[04:23:19,495][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-1-#30%testGrid-client2%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception.
class org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioException: null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1595)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:1516)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1289)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioRecoveryDescriptor.ackReceived(GridNioRecoveryDescriptor.java:195)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioRecoveryDescriptor.onHandshake(GridNioRecoveryDescriptor.java:278)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2.connected(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:617)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2.onFirstMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:492)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2.onMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:540)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$2.onMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:330)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:270)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.onMessageReceived(GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:2332)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:918)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1583)
```

I run server node on AIX with default configuration from Ignite 1.7.0 distr. And I run client node on Win7 with following configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
        <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
                    <property name="gridName" value="testGrid-client2"/>
                    <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
                    <!--<property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>-->
                    <property name="discoverySpi">
                               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                                           <property name="ipFinder">
                                                       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                                                                   <property name="addresses">
                                                                               <list>
                                                                                          <value>10.xxx.xxx.xxx:47500..47509</value>
                                                                              </list>
                                                                   </property>
                                                       </bean>
                                           </property>


        </bean>
```

where 10.xxx.xxx.xxx is IP address of my AIX machine.

Comment: What's processor and it's Endianness on AIX machine? Ignite currently doesn't support communication between nodes that run on processor architectures with different Endianness.

Comment: @Mitya thanks for the hint, processor on that AIX machine has big endian byte order

Comment: Looks like that's an issue. Try avoid such use cases.

Comment: @Mitya thanks for your help. I just can't understand why that's an issue, I thought Ignite runs inside platform-independece JVM and therefore should not rely on specific processor endianness

Comment: This is because for speed purposes Ignite communication protocol uses native byte order, and for now it's not configurable. I don't know about plans to change this, but you may ask about it on user list: user@ignite.apache.org.

Answer (score 1):

Big Endian architecture was supported pretty decent time ago. Presently, Ignite automatically detects an underlying platform endianness and switches to specific modes of operation. As far as I remember, Apache Ignite community members confirmed that Ignite works on Solaris and Power PC.